# given two scripts for deleting records in table(6 million rows) want to know which script will be better and why?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have table with 6 million records I am running archival script to delete around 5 million records. 
My script1 will do the deletion but the DBA said my script1 getting into more buffer gets and
he recommended the approach which is script2. I am confused how come script2 is better than script1.
So please review the scripts and reply which is the best approach and why.

script1 :

```
PROCEDURE archival_charging_txn(p_no_hrs     IN NUMBER,
                                  p_error_code OUT NUMBER,
                                  p_error_msg  OUT VARCHAR2) IS

    v_sysdate DATE := SYSDATE - p_no_hrs / 24;
    TYPE t_txn_id IS TABLE OF scg_charging_txn.txn_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    v_txn_id t_txn_id;
    CURSOR c IS
      SELECT txn_id FROM scg_charging_txn WHERE req_time < v_sysdate;  /* non unique index */
  BEGIN

    OPEN c;

    LOOP
      FETCH c BULK COLLECT
        INTO v_txn_id LIMIT 10000;

      IF v_txn_id.COUNT > 0 THEN
        FORALL i IN v_txn_id.FIRST .. v_txn_id.LAST
          DELETE FROM scg_charging_txn WHERE txn_id = v_txn_id(i);   /* Primary key based */

      END IF;

      COMMIT;

      EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c;

    COMMIT;
    p_error_code := 0;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      p_error_code := 1;
      p_error_msg  := substr(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
  END archival_charging_txn;
```

script 2:

```
PROCEDURE archival_charging_txn_W(p_no_hrs     IN NUMBER,
                                  p_error_code OUT NUMBER,
                                  p_error_msg  OUT VARCHAR2) IS


  BEGIN

    DELETE FROM scg_charging_txn WHERE req_time < SYSDATE - p_no_hrs / 24;


    COMMIT;
    p_error_code := 0;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      p_error_code := 1;
      p_error_msg  := substr(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
  END archival_charging_txn_W;
```

Comment: why not ask the DBA who provided the 2nd script? they would appear to be the best person to ask.

Comment: he is not a suffy guy!  with first approach he complained the buffer gets more so  we forced him to give a approach  he gave the second approach since he owns the the load report now he says second approach have no complaints.hence i want to post this and get it cleared so please do help

Answer (score 0):

the 1st script reads the table entries using the cursor, therefore more buffer gets, while the 2nd script just deletes the table entries.

I would prefer the 2nd script. in case you get troubles with locking the table for too log time, make a `LOOP UNTIL SQL%NOTFOUND` with `DELETE ... AND ROWNUM <= 10000; COMMIT;` inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deleting 5 million of 6 million rows, performance will suck.

You're better off doing CTAS.

Something like:

```
create table new_scg_charging_txn nologging as select * from scg_charging_txn WHERE req_time >= SYSDATE - p_no_hrs / 24;
```

If downtime is unacceptable, you may be able to do something similar, but wrap it with `DBMS_REDEFINITION`.

Comment: thanks for the reply!! but what will happen to the transactios that keep inserting in  the table scg_charging_txn  since with CTAS now new table created but applications pumping txns will store in the actual scg_charging_txn table so we loose all those txns again we cant syncup will be time consuming.

Comment: If you can't have any down time (constant transactions against scg_charging_txn, then, as I mentioned, you should look into DBMS_REDEFINITION.  Also, is this going to be a "one-time" operation, or part of a regularly recurring process?

Comment: its schedduled activity during off peak hours this script will execute and remove the previous day records